# ADODB not connecting

Tags: php, mysql, adodb

I have ADOdb being utilized on two sites.  On the first it works flawlessly, on the second, everything is the same except for the site uses a different database and login information, and it doesnt even seem to attempt a connection.

Using an incorrect table name or login information, doesnt result in an error output, or anything.

this is my code:

```
$DBTYPE = 'mysql';
$DBHOST = '***';
$DBUSER = '***';
$DBPASS = '***';
$DBNAME = 'fe';
// End Configuration

require_once($config['basedir'].'/libraries/adodb/adodb.inc.php');

$conn = &ADONewConnection($DBTYPE);
$conn->PConnect($DBHOST, $DBUSER, $DBPASSWORD, $DBNAME);
@mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
```

any idea why this wouldnt work? im completely at a loss now.  As I said there is no difference other than two seperate web hosts, one works, one doesnt.

Comment: are you sure you have error reporting ON in the second site? and since you are using a mysql db why not use the mysqli extension instead ?

Comment: Im so familiar with ADOdb that i would prefer to stick with it :/  and the first site is completely written with it.  Error reporting is on

Comment: ok i see, are there any unsual characters in your username/password... if so, do you have the correct encoding for the file?

Comment: There were, but i just changed the password to something alphanumeric, and tested that, still nothing

Comment: could it be that the DB is not allowing access (perhaps a host restriction? ie: can't connect except from a specific ip..) . What happens if you try to connect to the same DB used in the other site?

Comment: Im at a loss for words, i copy pasted an example from ADODB's site which has the connection using `NewADOConnection` instead of `ADONewConnection` and it worked.  Odd thing is, when i switched it back to `ADONewConnection` again, it remained working.  So maybe it was the password issue, thats the only thing that makes sense to me right about now, im quite confused.  If you post that as an answer I'll check it correct, unless i can figure out another explanation of why.  I was fighting with this for over 2 hours :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
$conn = &NewADOConnection($DBTYPE);
$conn->PConnect($DBHOST, $DBUSER, $DBPASSWORD, $DBNAME);
@mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
```

`NewADOConnection` instead of `ADONewConnection`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$conn = NewADOConnection($DBTYPE);
$conn->Connect($DBHOST, $DBUSER, $DBPASSWORD, $DB_NAME) or die("ERROR CONNECT " . $DBNAME);
$query = "SET NAMES 'UTF8'";

$rs = $db->Execute($query) or ("Error SQL. " . $db->ErrorMSG());
```